# Make Firefox forget a site was https

Tags: firefox

I do a bunch of testing of web server setups, and so I frequently change a given virtual host's default protocol from `http` to `https` and back.

Unfortunately, Firefox keeps remembering that a site used to be `https` and refuses to reconnect to it with `http`, at least for some after the last 
connection.

Is there a setting, or some stored value somewhere where I can make Firefox forget that it has ever seen this site before? I looked all over `about.config` and in the settings (I was looking for something rather similar to the "forget cookies" dialog) but came up empty.

Comment: Posting this as a comment because I'm not sure if this is definitely what you're looking for, but have you [tried resetting HSTS](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/clear-hsts-settings-chrome-firefox/)?

Comment: I did not know about this file, but the site I'm currently testing with does not appear in it. So it must be something else.

Comment: The hostname of my site shows up in `permissions.sqlite` in that directory, but I can't quite make sense of what the columns mean in contained table `moz_perms`.